# If $f$ is a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ then there exists $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=2\sin x_0$

Tags: calculus, functions

Prove/disprove: if a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ then there exists $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=2\sin x_0$.

Define: $g(x)=f(x)-2\sin x$

$g(\frac {\pi} 4)=f(\frac {\pi} 4)-2\sin\frac {\pi} 4$ note that $\begin{cases}f(\frac {\pi} 4) \le 1 \\ 1< 2\sin\frac {\pi} 4 \le 2\end{cases}\ $ so: $g(\frac {\pi} 4)<0$

$g(0)=f(0)-2sin0\Rightarrow g(0)=f(0)$, so if $f(0)=0$, then just take $x_0=0$ and we're done.

For $f(0)>0$ we'll know from IVT that here's $x_0\in [0,\frac {\pi} 4]$ such that $f(x_0)=2\sin x_0$.

But what if $f(0)<0$ as well ?

Comment: Regarding your question, what is the codomain of $f$?

Comment: $f(0)$ cannot be less than zero as the function $f$ takes values in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks Git and Vishal.

Comment: By the way, your conclusion uses IVT, not MVT.

Comment: Whoops, small mix up.